# Trying to access nearby places of type hospital in android app giving invalid request?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I am trying to access nearby hospitals in an android app by by using the following url url, but it is saying that it is an invalid request.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=171.0,74.8190934&radius=5000&types=hospital&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyBJ5fMauIQpTnuclgzozRCmGhMM_4PgfkY.
```

My google places browser api key is `AIzaSyBJ5fMauIQpTnuclgzozRCmGhMM_4PgfkY`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try your code without the presence of the API key and give a feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your location parameter is invalid. It's latitude, longitude if you were trying for the reverse (a latitude of 171 is outside possible values).